# Equivalent of Provider.value in Riverpod Flutter

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have been trying to migrate my old projects from `provider` to `riverpod`. What is the equivalent of using `Provider.value` in `riverpod`? What I am trying to do is, after authentication, I want to be able to access User from all places thus I am passing User down the widget tree using Provider.value like this:

```
Provider<AuthUser>.value(value: user);
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary advantage of Riverpod is that its not attached to the widget tree so there is no need to use `.value` , if the provider already exists in another route, it will use it, for a better example you would need to upload some code about what you're trying to code for a more specific answer

Comment: Edited the question on what I want to do.

Comment: watch(myAuthProvider).user will work the same in all your app, ProviderContainer from riverpod is at the beginning of your app so there is no need for .value

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar use case. What you could do is have a StateProvider and once the user is logged in, you update the state of this provider with user data. From now on other providers and widgets can get the user by getting the state of this provider using e.g. watch.